# Sum of file folder size based on file/folder name

Tags: powershell, sum

I have multiple folders across a number of SQL Servers that contain hundreds/thousands of databases. Each database comprises of three elements:

```
<dbname>.MDF
<dbname>.LDF
<dbname>files (Folder that contains db files/attachments)
```

I need to marry these files together and add up their total size, does anyone have any advice on how to do this?

EDIT : Just to clarify, I'm currently able to output the filesizes of the MDF/LDF files, I have a separate script that summarises the folder sizes. I need a method of adding together a .MDF/.LDF/DBFiles folder when their name matches. Bearing in mind all of the files are prefixed with the database name.

EDIT #2: The 2 options given so far sum together the .mdf/.ldf files with no problem, but do not add the folder size of the DBFiles folder. Does anyone have any input on how to amend these scripts to include a folder beginning with the same name.

First provided script:

```
$root = 'C:\db\folder'
Get-ChildItem "$root\*.mdf" | Select-Object -Expand BaseName |
ForEach-Object {
New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
  Database = $_
  Size     = Get-ChildItem "$root\$_*" -Recurse |
             Measure-Object Length -Sum |
             Select-Object -Expand Sum
}
}
```

Second provided script:

```
gci "c:\temp" -file -Include "*.mdf", "*.ldf" -Recurse | 
group BaseName, DirectoryName  | 
%{new-object psobject -Property @{FilesAndPath=$_.Name; Size=($_.Group | gci |  Measure-Object Length -Sum).Sum }    }
```

EDIT #3:

Thanks to Ansgar (below), the updated solution has done the trick perfectly. Updating question with final solution:

```
$root = 'C:\db\folder'
Get-ChildItem "$root\*.mdf" | Select-Object -Expand BaseName |
  ForEach-Object {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
      Database = $_
      Size     = Get-ChildItem "$root\$_*\*" -Recurse |
                 Measure-Object Length -Sum |
                 Select-Object -Expand Sum
    }
  }
```

Comment: Ok, I get your point, and I should have been clear. I currently am able to check and output the filesize of all contents of the folder. What I need to be able to do with those results is match each database with it's accompanying files and add them together.

Comment: Are these files/folders scattered, or are they kept together per database?

Comment: They are all kept in one folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enumerate just the .mdf files from your database folder, then enumerate the files and folders for each basename.

```
$root = 'C:\db\folder'
Get-ChildItem "$root\*.mdf" | Select-Object -Expand BaseName |
  ForEach-Object {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
      Database = $_
      Size     = Get-ChildItem "$root\$_*\*" -Recurse |
                 Measure-Object Length -Sum |
                 Select-Object -Expand Sum
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this Ansgar. Great stuff.

Comment: Hi Ansgar, I've updated my question with the problem I was seeing. It has added the MDF/LDF files together, but has left out the size of the associated folder. I originally thought it was calculating properly which is why I accepted the answer originally.

Comment: @KEW Apparently the path expression needs to be `$root\$_*\*` to have `Get-ChildItem` actually recurse into the subfolders. Updated my answer.

Comment: Ansgar, you're an absolute star. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

if you want the sum of sise files database by dir and name file (without extension), try it

```
gci "c:\temp" -file -Include "*.mdf", "*.ldf" -Recurse | 
group BaseName, DirectoryName  | 
%{new-object psobject -Property @{FilesAndPath=$_.Name; Size=($_.Group | gci | Measure-Object Length -Sum).Sum }    }
```

Modifiy a little  the include gci if necessary

Comment: Thank you for this Esperento-