# Passing PowerShell Output to CSV/Excel

Tags: excel, powershell, csv, export, output

I previously had asked a question regarding adding together files and folders with a common name and having them summed up with a total size ([Sum of file folder size based on file/folder name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40819483/sum-of-file-folder-size-based-on-file-folder-name)). This was successfully answered with the PS script below:

```
$root = 'C:\DBFolder'
Get-ChildItem "$root\*.mdf" | Select-Object -Expand BaseName |
  ForEach-Object {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
      Database = $_
      Size     = (Get-ChildItem "$root\$_*\*" -Recurse |
                 Measure-Object Length -Sum |
                 Select-Object -Expand  Sum  ) / 1GB
    } 
  }
```

This now leaves me with a list that is ordered by the 'Database' Property by default. I have attempted to use a `Sort-Object` suffix to use the 'Size' property with no joy. I have also attempted to use `Export-Csv` with confounding results.

Ideally, if I could pass the results of this script to Excel/CSV so I can rinse/repeat across multiple SQL Servers and collate the data and sort within Excel, I would be laughing all the way to the small dark corner of the office where I can sleep.

Just for clarity, the output is looking along the lines of this:

```
Database                                             Size
--------                                             ----
DBName1                                              2.5876876
DBName2                                              4.7657657
DBName3                                              3.5676578
```

Comment: How *exactly* have you "attempted to use `Sort-Object`/`Export-Csv`"? Show your code as well as actual and desired output.

Comment: I've answered my question, I had suffixed the script with Export-csv 'Pathname\test.csv' but had not added the pipe symbol immediately before it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was one pipe character that I had missed when using the Export-csv function. This resolved my problem.

```
$root = 'C:\DB\Databases'
Get-ChildItem "$root\*.mdf" | Select-Object -Expand BaseName |
  ForEach-Object {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
      Database = $_
      Size     = (Get-ChildItem "$root\$_*\*" -Recurse |
                 Measure-Object Length -Sum |
                 Select-Object -Expand  Sum  ) / 1GB
    } 
  } | Export-Csv 'C:\Test\test.csv'
```